# Using Nvim-Qt colors with regular Vim

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, color, neovim-qt

I have been using `nvim-qt` and I like it.

However I want to switch to regular `nvim`, but like other users I have had trouble with it.

So then I thought maybe I will just use plain `vim`. The issue is that I like the default colors of `nvim-qt`, so I would like to keep them. However, I can't seem to duplicate them. I tried a `.vimrc` like this:

```
set term=xterm-256color
set termguicolors
```

With `nvim-qt`, I get good looking colors like this:

[image: Untitled]

but with `vim` I get this:

[image: 2]

It's pretty close but some bolding is different. How can I resolve this? Note I am using Windows with Mintty.

https://gist.github.com/tycho/73401cd6aed7e733fc2b97a8de1ca03e

Comment: Fwiw, don’t set term in your vimrc or bashrc. Let the terminal emulator describe itself.

Comment: would it work if you `set termguicolors`, then `:hi statement cterm=bold` ?